# this.bind() uses first dataset only not second one

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a problem that I want to bind a dataset with the labels in the aspx form from code behind and I am using 2 datasets in a function but the problem is that it is binding first dataset only.

My code is like this:

```
 private void fill()
    {
        DateTime dat;
        if (txtDate.Text == "")
            dat = DateTime.Now;
        else
            dat = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate .Text , "M/d/yyyy", null);

        rtbl.LoadRoomTypes(_ds, SessionContext.PropertyID,dat);
        dlDashBoard.DataSource = _ds.Tables[rtbl.SqlEntityX];
        dlDashBoard.DataBind();

        foreach(DataListItem item in dlDashBoard .Items )
        {

            BindNestedItem(item.ItemIndex );


        }
        _ds = null;
        RoomTypeBAL rtbl1 = new RoomTypeBAL(0);


        rtbl1.LoadTotalFree(_ds3, SessionContext.PropertyID, dat);
        if(_ds3 !=null && _ds3.Tables[rtbl1 .SqlEntityX ].Rows.Count >0)
        this.DataBind();//Problem is here binding _ds always but I want to bind _ds3

    }
```

My source is like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="FreeRooms :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom1" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom1"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom2" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom2"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom3" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom3"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom4" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom4"].ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom5" runat="server" Text='<%#_ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom5"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblfreeRoom6" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom6"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tfreeroom7"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Arrivals :"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival1"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival2"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival3"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival4"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival5"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival6"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tarrival7"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="CheckOuts :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout1"].ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout2"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout3"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout4"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout5"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout6"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text='<%#  _ds3.Tables[0].Rows[0]["tcheckout7"].ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i believe u need to reset your DataSource, this.DataBind() is refer back to ds_

```
if(_ds3 !=null && _ds3.Tables[rtbl1 .SqlEntityX ].Rows.Count >0)
dlDashBoard.DataSource = _ds3.Tables[rtbl.SqlEntityX];
dlDashBoard.DataBind();
```

Comment: you havent understand my question

Comment: sad to heard that :( would you mind to specify your question clearly? :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all I’d really recommend that you switch to gridview instead of using table with a lot of inline labels that are really hard to manage. You can have the same functionality and a lot of using GridView control vs doing this by hand.

As to your problem – you need to set DataSource before doing DataBind(). How is class supposed to know to which source to bind to if you don’t tell it?

Comment: in source you can see I am setting binding text property of label to dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I got it I have to declare _ds3 as public